# Saving persistent data to a service with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

How do you all save data to a service using TypeScript?

If I have a service like this:

```
class MyService {
    persistentData: Object;

    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }

    private init = (): void => {
        this.persistentData = {};
    }

    public saveData = (data): Object {
        this.persistentData = data;
    }
}
```

How would I go about keeping the data consistent through different routes? Each time a new route is called, the service class is instantiated again, and the persistentData object is reset to be blank. Normally in regular JavaScript you could do:

```
angular
    .factory('myFactory', function() {
        var persistentData = {};

        return {
            setFormData: function(newData) {
                persistentData = newData;
            }
        }
    })
```

And this works. I must be missing something, can anyone help?

Comment: The JavaScript code is legal TypeScript code. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a class, then make the property static so that it can be shared across all instances of the class and don't set it back to `{}` each time a new instance is created:

```
class MyService {
    static persistentData: any = {};

    saveData = (data: any) => {
        MyService.persistentData = data;
    }
}
```